# c++ class with 'operator=' and vector, I don't know how to use it correctly

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

I tried to use operator= on a specific edge from a vector (of Edge) in a specific Vertex. but I got this error:

> source_file.cpp: In member function ‘void Graph::addEdges(int, int,
>   int, int)’: source_file.cpp:43:26: error: no match for ‘operator=’
>   (operand types are ‘std::vector’ and ‘Edge’)
>   arr[source].arr2[dest] = Edge(source, dest, a, b);

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

const int maxVer = 60;

struct Edge{
    int source;
    int dest;
    int a;
    int b;
    public:
    Edge() : a(0), b(0){};
    Edge(int source, int dest, int a, int b) : source(source), dest(dest), a(a), b(b) {}
    Edge& operator=(const Edge& e){
        source = e.source;
        dest = e.dest;
        a = e.a;
        b = e.b;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Vertex{
    int parent;
    int dest;
    bool visited;
    int numberEdges;
    string str;
    vector<Edge> arr2[maxVer-1];
};

class Graph{
    int vertexNumber=0;
    Vertex arr[maxVer];
    queue<int> que;
    public:
    void addEdges(int source, int dest, int a, int b){
        arr[source].arr2[dest] = Edge(source, dest, a, b);
        arr[dest].arr2[source] = Edge(dest, source, b, a);
        ++arr[source].numberEdges;
        ++arr[dest].numberEdges;
    }
};

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem? How can i fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Vertex` class when you do

```
vector<Edge> arr2[maxVer-1];
```

you don't declare one vector with the size of `maxVer-1` elements, you declare an *array* of `maxVer-1` number of vectors.

If you want a single vector then do:

```
struct Vertex
{
    // Declare the vector
    vector<Edge> arr2;
    // ... all other member variables...

    // Add constructor with a member initializer list
    Vertex()
        : arr2(maxVer-1)  // Initializes the vector to have maxVer-1 elements
    {}
};
```

<sub>Note the changed order, where `arr2` is declared *first*. If it's not then you have to add initialization of all other members in the constructor member initializer list.</sub>